# The use of a custom icon

Tags: icons, files

As it is for now there's no easy way to change a folder's icon with a custom one. Exampel I want to change my Steam folder which indicate it's Steam in that directory.
I have tried with **gio** command also with **gvfs-set-attribute** command but it is deprecated.

```
gio set -t string metadata::custom-icon file:///home/orion/.icons/ePapirus/48x48/places/folder-black-steam.svg
```

But it didn't work.
Is there a way to use custom icons in "Files"?

regards,

Comment: It's on the wishlist but it's been two years ago: https://github.com/elementary/files/issues/171

Comment: This is interesting: https://github.com/elementary/files/pull/1189

Comment: The only folders I found a way to change are the ones with icons - Pictures, Downloads, Documents... I was trying to add some new entries into directories file where these are listed with no luck.. It is a feature that I miss from other linux/osx distros